# AWS SQS error : SignatureDoesNotMatch HTTP error: 403

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-php-sdk

I'm working on a face tracking thought video `AWS Rekognition` (`StartFaceSearch`). It will return the job id. I have setup everything `SQS` `SNS` parts. **Here my problem** is i can't able to get a message from SQS using `receiveMessage()`. Even `listQueues()` also not working. It gives this below error.

> "ListQueues" on "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
>   < ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">Sender< Code >S (truncated...)
>   SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
>
> The Canonical String for this request should have been
>   'POST
>   / ....... < continue.............

The code as follow. AWS PHP SDK ver 3.64.11.

```
$queueUrl = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/facetrackingreceive";
        // Get the client from the builder by namespace
        $sqs_client = new SqsClient(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key'    => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
                'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            ),
            'version' => '2012-11-05',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'http' => [ 'verify' => false ],

        ));

        $result = $sqs_client->listQueues();

        foreach ($result->get('QueueUrls') as $queueUrl) {
            echo "$queueUrl\n";
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do as it suggests, check your AWS secret and signing method?

Comment: @ChrisCousins nope! I did it as above code. can suggest that link to check

Comment: something is wrong here; your POST is to to "sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" yet in your code it says "sqs.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com" ?

Comment: @ChrisCousins your are right but I have changed that error message. that's not a real problem. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I have solved the problem** by regenerating `access key`. I can't belive it
but there is something issue on it. I found that idea from this closed [issue](https://github.com/albogdano/elasticsearch-river-amazonsqs/issues/7). this issue was almost 4 year before now i got same error.

> Problem may occurred due to special characters in access/secret keys

After regenerating keys in `AWS console`. `SQS` all methods works fine with new `credentials`. Reported this as bug on [Github official repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1612).

Answer (score 0):

Yes replacing key with new will work in this case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).